# DataGrid freezing when Items size is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, desktop-application

I have a WPF project with a DataGrid that is bound to an Observable Collection.
This collection is populated using an async method. When the DataGrid is populating itself with the items, or page size changes,UI freezes for a few seconds. (more items to be displayed more it freezes).
Virtualization is enabled.Custom pagination logic is implemented.

DataGrid code

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding Page.VisibleGrid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="productsData"                      
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.1"CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  PreviewMouseWheel="productsData_PreviewMouseWheel" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                  DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization="True">
```

My custom paging code:

```
public class PageInfo<T> : BaseViewModel where T : class
{
    public event Action onPaging;
    public event Action<int, int> onPagingResult;

    public bool FireEvent { get; set; }

    private DashBoardViewModel dashboard;

    private RelayCommand goPageCommand;
    public RelayCommand GoPageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return goPageCommand ??
              (goPageCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
                {
                    if (param is string parameter)
                    {
                        if (parameter == "last")
                            CurrentPageIndex = PagesCount - 1;
                        else if (parameter == "first")
                            CurrentPageIndex = 0;
                        else if (parameter == "next")
                        {
                            if (HasNext)
                                CurrentPageIndex++;
                        }

                        else if (parameter == "previous")
                        {
                            if (HasPrev)
                                CurrentPageIndex--;
                        }
                    }

                    if (FireEvent)
                        FireWithOffsetAndLimit();
                    else
                        Move();
                },
                (param) =>
                {
                    if (param is string parameter)
                    {
                        if (parameter == "last") return CurrentPageIndex != PagesCount - 1;
                        else if (parameter == "first") return CurrentPageIndex != 0;
                        else if (parameter == "next") return HasNext;
                        else if (parameter == "previous") return HasPrev;
                    }
                    return false;
                }));
        }
    }

    public PageInfo(int pageSize, List<T> allItems, DashBoardViewModel dashBoard = null)
    {
        PageSize = pageSize;
        AllItems = allItems;
        CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        if (dashBoard == null)
            dashboard = Router.getInstance().CurrentPageContext as DashBoardViewModel;
        else
            dashboard = dashBoard;
    }

    private void FireWithOffsetAndLimit()
    {
        Offset = CurrentPageIndex * PageSize;
        Limit = PageSize;
        onPaging?.Invoke();
        onPagingResult?.Invoke(Offset, Limit);
    }

    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public int Limit { get; set; }

    private int pageSize;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get => pageSize;
        set
        {
            bool changed = pageSize != 0 && pageSize != value;
            pageSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(pageSize)));
            if (!FireEvent)
            {
                if (changed && CurrentPageIndex <= PagesCount - 1)
                {
                    Reinit();
                    Move();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Offset = 0;
                Limit = PageSize;
                onPaging?.Invoke();
                onPagingResult?.Invoke(Offset, Limit);
            }
        }
    }

    private int currentPageIndex;
    public int CurrentPageIndex
    {
        get { return currentPageIndex; }
        set
        {
            currentPageIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentPageIndex)));
        }
    }

    private int currentPageNumber;
    public int CurrentPageNumber
    {
        get { return currentPageNumber; }
        set
        {
            currentPageNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentPageNumber)));
        }
    }

    private int pagesCount;
    public int PagesCount
    {
        get
        {
            return pagesCount;
        }
        set
        {
            pagesCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PagesCount)));
        }
    }

    private List<T> allItems;
    public List<T> AllItems
    {
        get => allItems;
        set
        {
            allItems = value;
            if (!FireEvent)
            {
                Reinit();
                CurrentPageIndex = 0;
                Move();
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentPageNumber = CurrentPageIndex + 1;
                VisibleGrid = new SmartCollection<T>();
                VisibleGrid.AddRange(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AllItems)));
        }
    }

    private bool showFilter;
    public bool ShowFilter
    {
        get { return showFilter; }
        set
        {
            showFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ShowFilter"));
        }
    }

    private SmartCollection<T> visibleGrid;
    public SmartCollection<T> VisibleGrid
    {
        get => visibleGrid;
        set
        {
            visibleGrid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(VisibleGrid)));
        }
    }

    private bool hasNext;
    public bool HasNext
    {
        get => CurrentPageIndex < PagesCount - 1;
        set
        {
            hasNext = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasNext)));
        }
    }

    private bool hasPrev;
    public bool HasPrev
    {
        get => CurrentPageIndex > 0;
        set
        {
            hasPrev = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasPrev)));
        }
    }

    public void GoNext()
    {
        if (HasNext)
        {
            CurrentPageIndex++;
            Move();
            HasNext = CurrentPageIndex < PagesCount - 1;
        }
    }

    internal void Move()
    {
        if (AllItems != null)
        {
            CurrentPageNumber = CurrentPageIndex + 1;
            IEnumerable<T> collectionTaken = AllItems.Skip(CurrentPageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
            if (collectionTaken != null)
            {
                if (dashboard == null)
                    dashboard = Router.getInstance().CurrentPageContext as DashBoardViewModel;
                if (collectionTaken.Count() > 0)
                {
                    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
                    worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        var _itemsLock = new object();
                        VisibleGrid = new SmartCollection<T>();
                        var collection = e.Argument as IEnumerable<T>;
                        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(VisibleGrid, _itemsLock);
                        lock (_itemsLock)
                        {
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                VisibleGrid.AddRange(collection);
                            }));
                        }
                    };
                    worker.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        dashboard.IsLoading = e.ProgressPercentage < 100;
                    };
                    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
                    {
                        if (dashboard != null)
                            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => dashboard.IsLoading = false);
                    };
                    worker.RunWorkerAsync(collectionTaken);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void GoPrev()
    {
        if (HasPrev)
        {
            CurrentPageIndex--;
            Move();
            HasPrev = CurrentPageIndex > 0;
        }
    }

    internal void Refresh()
    {
        Reinit();
        CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        Move();
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AllItems)));
    }

    public void Reinit()
    {
        PagesCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)AllItems.Count / PageSize);
    }

    public void ResetPages(long rowCount)
    {
        PagesCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)rowCount / PageSize);
    }
}
```

My custom collections code:

```
 public class SmartCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = true;

        if (base.Items is List<T> itemList)
        {
            itemList.AddRange(list);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }

        _suppressNotification = false;

        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
    }
}
```

When I remove these columns, freezing fixes:

```
<!--#region Price -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Price" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding CProductPrice.Price, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat=F2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region 0.5 -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding CProductPrice.PriceHalf, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat=F2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region 1.5 -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding CProductPrice.PriceOneAndHalf, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat=F2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region Double -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Double" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding CProductPrice.PriceDouble, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat=F2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region Goblet -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Goblet" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding CProductPrice.PriceGoblet, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat=F2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region Free -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Free" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="toggleMultipleFree" PreviewMouseDown="toggleMultipleFree_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource btn}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="toggleFree" Click="toggleFree_Click" Focusable="False">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsFree, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:ThemeAssist.Theme="Light"
                                                  Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Tag="free"/>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
                    <!--#region Treat -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Treat" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="toggleMultipleTreat" PreviewMouseDown="toggleMultipleTreat_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource btn}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="toggleTreat" Click="toggleTreat_Click" Focusable="False">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFree, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False" materialDesign:ThemeAssist.Theme="Light" 
                                                  Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Tag="treat">
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--#endregion-->
```

Resouces:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DimGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0.5,0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f6f7fb"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_GotFocus"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="DataGridCell_KeyDown"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainGreen}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="IndianRed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainGreen}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatAccentBgButton}" x:Key="btn">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatAccentBgButton}" x:Key="btnPopup">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,10,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding DashBoardVM.MainVM._Size}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox}" x:Key="CheckStyle">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
                        <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="h:TextBoxHelper.InputFormat" Value="Decimal"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainBlue}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainRed}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

How to fix the code in order to eliminate freezing?